# Can I guess how each element of the domain of the indicator function is contributing to the output?

Tags: math, machine-learning

Given an indicator function that maps finite set `X` to `{0, 1}` and assuming the exact function of how this mapping occurs is unknown, can I learn how each element of `X` is contributing to the output simply by generating random samples of `X` and using ML?

Comment: you basically just defined a binary classification.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes.  This is a very basic machine learning problem: binary classification, supervised learning.

Use random samples of X *and* the indicator classification (0 | 1) as your data set.  You can feed this to a component analysis tool, or perhaps train a model and then look at the derived training function (which, supposedly, will approach the same functionality as your indicator function).

Learning to use these tools will take more learning on your part.  There is probably a ML or statistics support package in your favourite language that can help.  Since Stack Overflow is not really a tutorial site, I'll leave off here and let you get to those search terms and your next set of reading.